# Check if array exists inside 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to check if an array exists inside a 2D numpy array. But if two arrays have the same components the program thinks they are equal, I want to differentiate two arrays that have the same values but in different order. I'm trying this code but it doesn't work as intended:

```
a=np.array([255,254,255])
b=np.array([254,255,255])
c=np.array(b)
if a not in c: #this line says it exists, it shouldnt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the numpy methods `any` and `all`

```py
if (a == c).all(0):
    #do stuff
```

The comparison compares each element of each array and creates a new array of booleans as to whether entries at the same index in both arrays are equal.

The all method then returns a single boolean based on the booleans in the array. The `0` parameter specifics you are looking on axis 0 (the only one in a 2D array),

Answer (score 0):

Use `all` to check if all the elements of a numpy array are equal:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([255, 254, 255])
b = np.array([254, 255, 255])
c = np.array(b)

if not all(a == c):
    pass
```